# Invalid URL. Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created search form:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>All locations</option>
                        <option>Москва</option>
                        <option>Петербург</option>
                        <option>Казань</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <!-- <button> Search </button> -->
                     <button  class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

When I input "c++" I go to http://127.0.0.1:8001/search/?q=c%2B%2B&q2=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0  (Result is OK, **but '+' is interpreted as %2B**)

When I click pagination "next" I receive

> http://127.0.0.1:8001/search/?vacancy=2&q=c++&q2=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0 (ERROR Page not found)
>
> I need http://127.0.0.1:8001/search/?vacancy=2&q=c%2B%2B&q2=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0

How can I fix this (convert '+' to '%2B')?

**vacancy_list.html**

```
{% extends 'vacancy_list/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container " style="margin:20px;"> <!-- wrapper for all containers -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px; font-size: 2rem;">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>All locations</option>
                        <option>Москва</option>
                        <option>Петербург</option>
                        <option>Казань</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <!-- <button> Search </button> -->
                     <button  class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1><a href="{% url 'vacancy_detail' pk=vacancy.pk %}">{{vacancy.title}}</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p> {{ vacancy.salary}} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="white-space:normal">
            <p class="text-secondary">{{vacancy.company_key.name}}</p>
            <p> Описание вакансии: Компания Sixhands, занимающаяся разработкой мобильных приложений и веб-порталов в Санкт-Петербурге, ищет Backend-разработчика для создания серверной части мобильных приложений.
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <p style="margin-left: 5px;">{{vacancy.city}} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p style="margin-right: 5px;"> {{vacancy.date_str }} </p>
                </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    {% endfor %}


    <!-- Paginator -->
    <div class="container" style="font-size: 2rem;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/?vacancy={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
        </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/?vacancy={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Next</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- wrapper end -->

{% endblock %}
```

**search_result.html**

```
{% extends 'vacancy_list/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container " style="margin:40px;"> <!-- wrapper for all containers -->

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 2rem;">
        <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <select name="q2" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                        <option>All locations</option>
                        <option>Москва</option>
                        <option>Петербург</option>
                        <option>Казань</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                     <button> Search </button>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h1><a href="{% url 'vacancy_detail' pk=vacancy.pk %}">{{vacancy.title}}</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right">
                    <p> 40000 </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" style="white-space:normal">
            <p class="text-secondary">{{vacancy.company_key.name}}</p>
            <p> Описание вакансии: Компания Sixhands, занимающаяся разработкой мобильных приложений и веб-порталов в Санкт-Петербурге, ищет Backend-разработчика для создания серверной части мобильных приложений.
        </div>


    </div>
    {% endfor %}


    <!-- Paginator -->
    <div class="container" style="font-size: 2rem;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/search?vacancy={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}&q={{ query }}&q2={{query2}}">Previous</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Previous</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
        </li>
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/search?vacancy={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&q={{ query }}&q2={{query2}}">Next</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">Next</span>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- wrapper end -->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing query parameters when you switch pages.
Here:

```html
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/search?vacancy={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}&q={{ query }}&q2={{query2}}">Next</a></li>
{% else %}
   <li class="page-item disabled">
      <span class="page-link">Next</span>
   </li>
{% endif %}
```

You need to pass the parameters from the previous request here something like this:

```html
{% if page_obj.has_next %}
   <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{ request.get_full_path }}&vacancy={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
{% else %}
   <li class="page-item disabled">
      <span class="page-link">Next</span>
   </li>
{% endif %}
```

See [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#methods).